# How can I choose a Visual C# class template in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to commence building an ASP.NET web application with Visual Studio 2019. I have VS Community installed with 'ASP.NET and web development' and '.NET desktop development' packages installed. The following is a screenshot of my 'Workloads' tab:

[image]

After installing I selected Create a New Project and selected 'ASP.NET Web Application'.

With the project and the folder tree displaying in the solution explorer (right hand side), I left clicked on 'Controller' folder and selected New -> Class. I wanted to select a Class template for Visual C# but instead can only see Visual Basic options listed. How can I source a Visual C# class template, and is there an installation step that I might have missed along the way?

[image]

Thanks,

Robert

London, UK

Comment: Are you sure you selected "C#" when you created that *project*?

Comment: I selected Create a New Project and selected 'ASP.NET Web Application'.         You probably and unintentionally picked the VB.NET version of this... which will filter-screw-you as you have seen.  Go create a new project (again) and carefully pick the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, pay special attention to the template, as they somewhat can overlap.

I'm drawn arrows and circles around the key points.

The below is what shows up when you do a New Project.

There are filters like "Language" and "Platforms" and "Project Types" that may be filtering out your desired.  Pick "All, All, All" to make sure this is not happening.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thankyou! It's always a reassuring start point to know you're working with the language that you intended. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to create a C# project, make sure you select the correct project template.

You can create a asp.net web application with either c# (which gives you .cs files) or visual Basic (that works with .vb files).

[image: various c# projects including visual basic]

Make sure to select the correct c# template.